# Docusign Email Address Undefined

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending an envelope using the Send to Docusign button, but i am getting an error

> Invalid envelope.Email address is undefined.

Please find the below code which i have written on the Docusign Button

```
{!URLFOR("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope", null,[SourceID = Authority_Granting__c.Id,
DST = $Label.Docusign_Template,
CCRM = "Decision Maker - Signer 1",
CCTM = "Decision Make",
CRL = "Email~"+ Authority_Granting__c.OwnerEmail+";FirstName~"+ Authority_Granting__c.Name +";LastName~" + Authority_Granting__c.Name + ";Role~Signer_1,RoutingOrder~1",
LA = '0',
LF = '0'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the `Authority_Granting__c.OwnerEmail` is a good email address.

To debug:

1. Does the button ever work? Or never works?
2. Check the API log on DocuSign to see exactly what is being sent to create the envelope. See https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging
3. As a test, try setting the button to check that the rest of your button is working as expected.

   CRL = "Email~"+ "your_email@your_domain.com" +";FirstName~"+ Authority_Granting__c.Name +";LastName~" + Authority_Granting__c.Name + ";Role~Signer_1,RoutingOrder~1",